# Unexpected StackOverflowException reading from a property

Tags: c#

I found the mistake in the common code, but i have no clue where I make the mistake. It looks like my brain has a stack overflow also :-).
Here is the code where the stack overflow comes from:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<TestStep> TestSteps
{
    get { return TestSteps; }
    set { TestSteps = value; }
}
```

Comment: `get { return TestSteps; }` Put a breakpoint on that line of code. Run until you hit the breakpoint. Then step to the next line of code. Do that a few times. What happens? Why do you think that happens?

Answer (score 4):

The property needs a *backing field*:

```
private ObservableCollection<TestStep> testSteps;
public ObservableCollection<TestStep> TestSteps
{
    get { return testSteps; }
    set { testSteps = value; }
}
```

Or you use an *auto-implemented* property:

```
public ObservableCollection<TestStep> TestSteps { get; set; }
```

---

Since you typically create ObservableCollections only once and later only add or remove items, the property should be readonly and initialized:

```
public ObservableCollection<TestStep> TestSteps { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<TestStep>();
```

---

In case it really needs to be settable, and since it seems to be a property in a view model, you should fire a property change notification in its setter, e.g. the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

```
private ObservableCollection<TestStep> testSteps;
public ObservableCollection<TestStep> TestSteps
{
    get { return testSteps; }
    set
    {
        testSteps = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TestSteps)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Both the getter and setter of the property calls themselves recursively.